# Force action Bar show search view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am able to expand search view by action like this

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:title="Search"
          android:showAsAction="never|collapseActionView"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

But i have a 3-tab activity and i'd like to SearchView be always expanded
How may I do that?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Two steps are necessary.

First, you have to make sure your search menu item is always shown as an action and never moved into the overflow menu. To achieve this set the search menu item's `showAsAction` attribute to `always`:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

Second, make sure the action view is not shown in iconified (i.e. collapsed) mode by default. To do this call `setIconifiedByDefault(false)` on your search view instance:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_activity, menu);

    MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchViewItem.getActionView();
    [...]
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return true;
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: getting NPE at thsi line  searchView.setIconifiedByDefault     i have used this code         SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
       searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

Comment: Try get SearchView by MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)) if you are using AppCompat SearchView